# vim replace crontab schedule section

Tags: regex, vim, replace

I want to replace the e.g `*/5 * * * *` in an crontab with something else (in my case i piped the whole crontab in an file and want to remove these sections completely to make it executable as shell script)
I tried for example this:

`:%s/*\/5 * * * *//g` -> replaces just the `*/5` part, but leaving `* * * *`

Can someone help me here please ?

Comment: maybe just flagging it as unuseful isn´t the right way to do it. At least tell my why :-)

Answer (score 1):

The `{pattern}` in [`:help :substitute`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/change.txt.html#%3Asubstitute) is a regular expression; you cannot simply insert the literal search text as-is, but have to *escape* stuff. In particular, there are two problems in your command:

- You're using the default `/` delimiter in `:substitute`, but you also have this character inside the pattern (`*/5`). That `/` either needs to be escaped (`\/`), or you need to choose another separator (any non-alphanumeric non-whitespace ASCII character will do, e.g. `:%s#...#...#g`).
- The `*` is a *multi item* ([`:help /star`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/pattern.txt.html#%2Fstar)); unless it is escaped, it does not match itself, but indicates the multiplicity of the previous atom. Again, you can either escape every instance (`\*`), or switch the whole regular expression to what is called "very nomagic" mode in Vim, which means that most characters lose their special meaning and are taken literally (except for a backslash, which still needs to be escaped); [`:help /\V`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/pattern.txt.html#%2F%5CV)
- As you expect the pattern to only appear once in a line, you can drop the `/g` flag. To nail down the pattern even more, you could add a "beginning of line" anchor (`^`) at the front. This is not critical, but prevent unintended matches.
- If you're now asking why this regular expression syntax is complicating things so much (a literal search would be much easier), this is not the case. The power of regular expressions allows great simplification. For example, the repetition of `*` could be rewritten as `\( \*\)\+` (repeat arbitrarily) or `\( \*\)\{4}` (exactly four times). (Though I wouldn't recommend this with your example, as it would make it more complex and doesn't save typing.)

So, here are two variants (escaping / different delimiter and very nomagic mode):

```
:%s/\*\/5 \* \* \* \*//
:%s#\V*/5 * * * *##
```